# Problems in prompt with new users in debian 7 wheezy

Tags: useradd

I have debian 7 x64 wheezy machine on digital ocean. Every time I add a new user the user prompt is empty. I only have a dollar (**$**) and nothing like **shikhar@server:** on my prompt. I cannot access history as well, pressing up and down types **^[[A** and the tab key doesn't list anything as well.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the option `-s /bin/bash` while creating new users this will setup '/bin/bash' as default (login-)shell for your newly created user.

You can always change your current shell to bash with `exec bash`.
Existing users can be edited with `vipw` (there you can change the default shell)

Answer (score 1):

Check out your /etc/passwd and makes sure the last field for the user (shell) is set to /bin/bash instead of /bin/sh